# Java Spring: Why making a call to /logout redirects to /login

Tags: java, spring

I'm creating a statless webapp backend that provides bunch of Rest API endpoints. The `WebSecurityConfig` class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

When I make a call to `/logout` endpoint, I expect to get `Access Denied` and 403 http status code in the response, but I get this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1495012033216,
  "status": 405,
  "error": "Method Not Allowed",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
  "path": "/login"
}
```

This is what I get with or without including the authentication JWT in the header. Why ? I don't have anything specific to `/logout` so why does this happen ?

I saw some questions before that `login?logout` gets the same behavior, but nothing regarding `/logout`. How should I override this behavior and make it just like any other Rest endpoints ?

What are the benefits of this default behavior ?

Comment: can you share your controller and request

Comment: There is no controller for the logout endpoint. My request is a simple POST call to the the /logout endpoint.

Comment: you are requesting /logout while you do not have a mapped url to /logout?

Comment: Yes. I do this with `/somethingthatdoesntexist` and it returns `Access Denied` response, as all requests must be authenticated.

Comment: yeah you are clearly stating that all your requests are authenticted in your configuration .anyRequest().authenticated()

Comment: the question is what is special about `/logout` that responds different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144439/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-arian-hosseinzadeh).